# Joomla! 2.5 media manager is only showing last item

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've suddenly started seeing an odd problem.

My media manager is only showing one item. The tree view shows all the directories, but the list of items in any given directory only shows the LAST item (case-insentive alphabetical).

I've checked things like the permissions on the files/folders and they're all the same. Uploading new images is not a problem, except that they don't appear in any list.

And yes I can see the contents of the folder in ftp.

And I'm a superuser.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Did you inspect the error logs for any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error with joomla's output buffering in the media module (administrator/components/com_media/views/) Echoing the results of a render call in {module type}/tmpl/default.php are causing an error.

To work around this I simply concatenated the output of the render calls into a string variable during the loop. Then forced output buffering on (ob_start()) and echoed the variable at the end of the script.

This is a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but joomla is no platform to play wack-a-mole with.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but your presentation probably isn't very useful to the typical Joomla user (who isn't a PHP programmer). Are you able to provide code snippets?